# Wait for function execution chain to finish

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am having a little problem, my JS code is not executing the way I want it to be. my code :

```
function mrInterval(){
    interval = setInterval(function() {
       if (!loadInProgress && typeof stepz[testindexz] == "function") {
           console.log("step " + (testindexz + 1));
           stepz[testindexz]();
           testindexz++;
       }
       if (typeof stepz[testindexz] != "function") {
           console.log("Crawling completed!");
           clearInterval(interval);
       }
    }, 30);
};

function getPairs(){
    var arr;
    stepz = [
        function(){
            page.open('http://data.bter.com/api/1/pairs');
        },
        function(){
            var mycont = page.plainText;
            arr = JSON.parse(mycont);
            console.log(arr);
            return arr;
        }
    ];

    mrInterval();
};

var xx = getPairs();
console.log(xx);
```

my Output is not what I expected :

```
undefined // came from last line of code (console.log(xx))
step 1
load started
load finished
step 2
[Data that i need ] // It came from console.log inside stepz[1] in getpairs
Crawling completed!
```

so the Issue as far as I can see, my code did not wait for the execution of the function getpairs() when I assigned to a variable. what I should make in order for my Code to not execute further untill all Chain of functions inside function (getpairs) is Over.

Comment: Your function starts up a timer. Starting a timer **returns immediately**.  The code does not wait for the timer to go off.

Comment: hmm I see, well how to fix that ?

Comment: ?? "fix"?  That's just the way browser timer mechanisms work. If you want to wait until a process is finished, put your code in the callback handler somewhere.

Comment: @Pointy yea I can make that, I was hoping though for an easier and cleaner way to do so.

Comment: JavaScript in most environments just doesn't have a "wait for a while and then keep going" mechanism. There's just the callback technique.

Comment: @Pointy I am aware of that, thats why I did the callback inside mrInterval() function do my code wait till page load. I just didnt know that timer will return Immediately

Comment: `getPairs` doesn't return anything. The only function with a return value is `stepz[1]`, but that only returns it to your anonymous setInterval callback function, which does nothing with it.